# How do I get the line numbers to permanently appear in vim

Tags: vimrc, linux, bash

I keep wanting to customize vim, how do I get the line numbers to show up everytime i open up VIM.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is a duplicate of our very first question, so I’ve closed it. You might want to take a look at the [tour], [help], or [meta] if you’re curious about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys! I just had to go into the vimrc file in the etc/vim directory and enter :set number on the last line. Thanks so much for your help yall.

Comment: It's not a great idea to modify the system vimrc. You should create a personal vimrc. See `:help vimrc`.

Comment: Also worth noting that in your vimrc you’ll want `set number` i.e. without the initial `:`.

Comment: I can also recommend to read through the most `usr_<num>` fils (just execute `:h` in normal mode and read the text)! They include many neat tricks with vim :)